# If one were to recreate the sound of thunder ripping....

Tags: design

How?

You know, when it just tears through the air, ethereally, with that jagged saw like sound and not so much bass but more hf reverberation.  For example over an open plain.  Just the jagged split and specifically the reverberation.

Answer (score 5):

Contact mic a large sheet of architectural aluminum. Take one end in your hands and slowly pull back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

I'd analyse the real thing - play it at half speed, quarter speed, backwards etc and see what those sounds evoked or reminded you of, then you could try creating that sound & applying the opposite effect... the very complex multiple delay/echo that occurs from gunshots in eg a canyon would be a possible element too, recreate that delay chain & then try processing the half or quarter speed analysis recreation with it...

Answer (score 1):

Contact mic on ripping tin foil.

Answer (score 1):

I always think a storm is coming when I hear my neighbor rolling out their large plastic recycling bins.

Comment: I've thought that more than once, myself.

Answer (score 0):

Contact mic on a piece of thick paper and tear it. Distort that. Or just mic it normally, duplicate it, pitch one down, distort/time stretch to taste.

Answer (score 0):

Bowling balls across the floor above you...  (I'm only half serious.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'thunder' IR on any one of the suggested contact mic recording suggestions. Thunder is always a great source to use as an impulse response. Playing with the length of the thunder can hugely influence the sound.